# transform data set so that each record represent unique place rather than multiple records for same place using r

Tags: r, dplyr, dataset, apply

I have a dataset with following records:

```
ID type    description name   colony zip

1  officer1 general    sam    maria  20909
1  officer2 general    phil   maria  20909
1  officer3 general    horton maria  20909
2  officer1 general    tony   santa  20979
```

I want my output to be :

```
ID  description  colony   zip     officer1 officer2 officer3

1   general      maria    20909   sam      phill    horton
2   general      santa    20979   tony
```

How can i achieve this using r, I want zip or location to be unique

Answer (score 0):

Use `spread`

```
> library(tidyr)
> df1 %>% spread(type, name)
  ID description colony   zip officer1 officer2 officer3
1  1     general  maria 20909      sam     phil   horton
2  2     general  santa 20979     tony     <NA>     <NA>
```

Comment: thanks! but in my dataset it is throwing this error {Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows}